# Timer Stops When Phone Goes Into Airplane Mode, Won't Restart After Leaving AM

Tags: ios, swift, dispatchertimer

OK. Looked through the possible answers, but I don't see my issue here.

I have a fairly bog-standard GCD repeating timer:

```
class RepeatingGCDTimer {
    /// This holds our current run state.
    private var state: _State = ._suspended

    /// This is the time between fires, in seconds.
    let timeInterval: TimeInterval
    /// This is the callback event handler we registered.
    var eventHandler: (() -> Void)?

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     This calculated property will create a new timer that repeats.

     It uses the current queue.
     */
    private lazy var timer: DispatchSourceTimer = {
        let t = DispatchSource.makeTimerSource()    // We make a generic, default timer source. No frou-frou.
        t.schedule(deadline: .now() + self.timeInterval, repeating: self.timeInterval)  // We tell it to repeat at our interval.
        t.setEventHandler(handler: { [unowned self] in  // This is the callback.
            self.eventHandler?()    // This just calls the event handler we registered.
        })
        return t
    }()

    /// This is used to hold state flags for internal use.
    private enum _State {
        /// The timer is currently paused.
        case _suspended
        /// The timer has been resumed, and is firing.
        case _resumed
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     Default constructor

     - parameter timeInterval: The time (in seconds) between fires.
     */
    init(timeInterval inTimeInterval: TimeInterval) {
        self.timeInterval = inTimeInterval
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     If the timer is not currently running, we resume. If running, nothing happens.
     */
    func resume() {
        if self.state == ._resumed {
            return
        }
        self.state = ._resumed
        self.timer.resume()
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     If the timer is currently running, we suspend. If not running, nothing happens.
     */
    func suspend() {
        if self.state == ._suspended {
            return
        }
        self.state = ._suspended
        self.timer.suspend()
    }

    /* ############################################################## */
    /**
     We have to carefully dismantle this, as we can end up with crashes if we don't clean up properly.
     */
    deinit {
        self.timer.setEventHandler {}
        self.timer.cancel()
        self.resume()   // You need to call resume after canceling. I guess it lets the queue clean up.
        self.eventHandler = nil
    }
}
```

Works great!

...except when it doesn't.

That would be when I put the device into Airplane Mode.

At that point, the timer stops firing.

Even when I come out of Airplane Mode, the timer doesn't restart.

The app uses UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true/false to keep the app awake, but that doesn't seem to keep the events coming.

Can anyone clue me into what's happening here, and how I might be able to work around it?

This app needs to work in Airplane Mode. In fact, it is most likely to be used in Airplane Mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. I think I solved this. As is often the case with these things, it's PEBCAK.

I have a routine that stops the timer when the app is backgrounded, and failed to put in a corresponding restart for when it is foregrounded.

When I slide up the Control Center, it backgrounds the app.

My bad.

Yeah, it's embarrassing, but I want to leave this question here as a warning to others.

Comment: Props to you for explaining what went wrong so others can learn from your mistake. (Voted)

Comment: "Good judgment comes from experience. Experience comes from bad judgment." -Will Rogers, but Originally Attributed to Nasrudin